# Modifying a Rakefile to allow JRuby migrations with the sinatra-activerecord gem

Tags: rake, sinatra, jruby

I've got my migration files, but I need to reference the database creds from config/database.yml

Now this gem: [sinatra-activerecord](https://github.com/bmizerany/sinatra-activerecord)

tells me that I should have these references in the app.rb ( the main sinatra directory folder )

aside: this seems weird as im running the migrations with rake. Shouldn't it be in the Rakefile?

BUT how do I connect up the app.rb file with the database credentials in config/database.yml ?